OAuth 2.0 Not Working Properly with Kakao Login in React App
I'm a computer science student
I'm sorry if there are any typos in my english
If you need more information my code ask to me

I’m implementing Kakao and Naver login with OAuth 2.0 in my React app. The login process appears to succeed, and the URL changes to indicate successful login (with the code parameter in the URL), but no user information is being logged to the console, and nothing is stored in local storage. Additionally, I’m not seeing any console output from console.log statements in my callback component.

Here’s a summary of my setup:
1. I have configured navigate("/login/com") in my code to redirect upon successful login, which corresponds to the redirect URI (http://localhost:3000/login/com) specified in the Kakao developer console.
2. I’m initializing the Kakao SDK with window.Kakao.init("YOUR_KAKAO_APP_KEY") in the callback component, and the SDK seems to load without errors.
3. Despite the URL indicating success, I’m not receiving any data from Kakao’s API, and console.log("Kakao User Info:", userData) does not output any user info.

Here's my code
//KakaoCallback.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const KakaoCallback = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("KakaoCallback useEffect 실행됨"); // 로그 추가

    const code = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("code");
    console.log("Authorization Code:", code); // 받은 인증 코드 출력

    if (code && window.Kakao) {
      if (!window.Kakao.isInitialized()) {
        window.Kakao.init("MY_KAKAO_JS_KEY");
        console.log("Kakao SDK initialized");
      }

      window.Kakao.Auth.login({
        success: (authObj) => {
          console.log("로그인 성공:", authObj);
          const accessToken = authObj.access_token;
          console.log("Kakao Access Token:", accessToken);

          fetch("https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/user/me", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
          })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((userData) => {
              console.log("Kakao User Info:", userData);
              if (userData.id) {
                localStorage.setItem("kakaoUserInfo", JSON.stringify(userData));
                navigate("/login/com");
              } else {
                console.error("사용자 정보 불러오기 실패:", userData);
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error fetching user info:", error);
            });
        },
        fail: (err) => {
          console.error("Kakao login failed", err);
        },
      });
    }
  }, [navigate]);

  return <h2>카카오 로그인 중...</h2>;
};

export default KakaoCallback;

import styles from "./Login.module.css";
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const clientId = "CLIENT_ID"; // 네이버에서 발급받은 Client ID를 입력하세요
  const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/login/com"; // 리다이렉트 URI를 설정합니다
  const state = "RANDOM_STATE_STRING"; // 보안을 위한 임의 문자열
  const loginUrl = `https://nid.naver.com/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
    redirectUri
  )}&state=${state}`;
  console.log("Naver Login URL:", loginUrl); // loginUrl을 콘솔에 출력

  const handleKakaoLogin = () => {
    if (!window.Kakao) {
      console.error("Kakao SDK가 로드되지 않았습니다.");
      return;
    }

    if (!window.Kakao.isInitialized()) {
      window.Kakao.init("MY_JS_KEY"); // 자신의 JavaScript 키로 교체
      console.log("Kakao SDK initialized");
    }

    window.Kakao.Auth.authorize({
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/login/com",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.LoginPage}>
      <div className={styles.Login}>
        <div className={styles.Login_form}>
          <div className={styles.Login_form_top}>
            <h1 className={styles.Login_form_top_h1}>Welcome to the BUDDA!</h1>
            <p className={styles.Login_form_top_p}>
              Discover new and delicious recipes, share your favorites, and
              connect with a community of food lovers. Join us and start your
              culinary journey today!
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.LoginInput_div}>
            <a href={loginUrl}>
              <button className={styles.LoginBtn}>네이버로 로그인</button>
            </a>
            <button className={styles.LoginBtn} onClick={handleKakaoLogin}>
              카카오톡으로 로그인
            </button>
            <Link to="/login/signup" className={styles.signup}>
              <div>If you don't have an account, click me!</div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

What I've Tried

Double-checked the clientId, clientSecret, and redirectUri values in both my code and the Kakao developer console.

Confirmed that the console.log statements are correctly placed but still don’t output any data.

Ensured the redirect URI in the Kakao developer console matches navigate("/login/com").


Issue:
The KaKao User Info and other console.log statemnets dont apper in the console, and there's no data in local storage, despite seeing the correct URL redirect.
Question:
Why might the console.log statements not show any output, and why am i not getting the user information as expected? Is there an issue with my code setup or OAuth configuration?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
